# Prove XML is Well Formed on Nifi

Tags: xml, apache-nifi, well-formed

I'm trying to prove my XML is well formed on Nifi.

I already validate it against some schema, but sometimes I do not have a schema and so wish to just confirm it is well formed. However all the XML processers seem to require a schema or such and don't just show it being well formed.

Can anyone privde some assitance? Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to kjhughes's answer (specific to NiFi), if you always know the root tag (let's call it "root"), you can use the XSD mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003982/xml-schema-that-allows-anything-xsdany) with the [ValidateXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateXml/index.html) processor.

If you don't know the root tag, you can use [ExecuteGroovyScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/index.html) with the "Failure strategy" property set to "transfer to failure" and "Script Body" set to the following script:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
InputStream i = flowFile.read()
new XmlSlurper().parse(i)
i.close()
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

Comment: I ended up using a XSD containing the root element tag as that was consistent across my XML.

Answer (score 0):

Simply attempt to parse it using any conformant XML parser.

If it [parses successfully](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-wfc), that is, with no fatal errors, 
then it is [***well-formed***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-wellformed):

> **well-formedness constraint**
>
> [Definition: A rule which applies to all [well-formed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-wellformed) XML
>   documents. Violations of well-formedness constraints are [fatal
>   errors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-fatal).]