# Is it possible to allow any valid XML as a child of an element in an XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I know the whole point of an XSD is to define the structure of the the XML, but is it possible to let a child be ***any valid XML***?  For example:

If I have this XSD

```
<xsd:complexType name="soExample">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="field1" type="xsd:integer" />
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

A valid XML is

```
<soExample>
  <field1>25</field1>
</soExample>
```

Now I want a special field `field2` which allows me to put any XML that can be parsed inside, XSD would look like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="soExample">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="field1" type="xsd:integer" />
    <xsd:element name="field2" type="so:special" />
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And a valid XML would be:

```
<soExample>
  <field1>25</field1>
  <field2>
    <anything>3</anything>
  </field2>
</soExample>
```

or

```
<soExample>
  <field1>25</field1>
  <field2>
    <cars>
      <favorite>"miata"</favorite>
    </cars>
  </field2>
</soExample>
```

I have a feeling this isn't possible because there's not a good way to resolve the types... but worth asking.

Comment: I suspect that when you say "any valid XML", you actually mean "any well-formed XML". Well-formed XML is valid only if it conforms to a schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, the purpose of `xsd:any` is to allow ***any*** XML at a given point in an XML document:

```
<xsd:element name="field2"/>
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any processContents="skip"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

For an explanation of the various values supported for `xsd:any/@processContents`, see [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420156/290085).

Note, you could also simply not specify the content model of `field2`:

```
<xsd:element name="field2"/>
```

See also [XML Schema that allows anything (xsd:any)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003982/290085).